# rust borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust

This is part of my code

```
pub async fn json_to(info: web::Json<Info>, data: web::Data<AppState>) -> String {
   
    let pool = data.pool_redis.clone();
    let conn = pool.get().await.unwrap();
    let mut a = conn.cluster.clone().unwrap();

    let redis_handle = RedisHandle::new(a);
    let user = redis_handle
        .get_user(
            info.u_id.to_string(),
            vec!["guild_positions", "guild_pending", "guild_folders"],
        )
        .await;

    let lists: Vec<String> = serde_json::from_str(&guild_position).unwrap();
    let v8 = vec!["1".to_string(), "2".to_string()];
    // let v8: Vec<&str> = v8.iter().map(move |x| x.as_str()).collect();
    let v8: Vec<&str> = lists.iter().map(|x| x.as_str()).collect();

    let my_nicks = redis_handle
        .get_user_guild_nick(info.u_id.clone().to_string(), v8)
        .await
        .unwrap();
   format!("done")
```

In `let v8: Vec<&str> = lists.iter().map(|x| x.as_str()).collect();` an error will be displayed

[image]

But if it’s okay

```
    let v8 = vec!["1".to_string(), "2".to_string()];
    let v8: Vec<&str> = v8.iter().map(move |x| x.as_str()).collect();
```

How should I use `lists` without prompting ownership

This is the `get_user_guild_nick` function

```
    pub async fn get_user_guild_nick(
        &self,
        user_id: String,
        fields: Vec<&'static str>,
    ) -> Result<HashMap<&'static str, Option<String>>> {

        let mut _con = self.connect.clone();
        let key = KEYMAP["user_nick"].replace("%s1", &user_id);

        let result: Vec<Option<String>> = cmd("hmget")
            .arg(key)
            .arg(&fields)
            .query_async(&mut _con)
            .await
            .unwrap_or(vec![None]);
        let mut map: HashMap<&'static str, Option<String>> = HashMap::new();
        let iter = fields.iter().enumerate();
        for (k, v) in iter {
            map.insert(v, result[k].clone());
        }
        Ok(map)
    }
```

Comment: Hello, wath about &guild_position? I tried some scenario but your snippet is not relevant for analysis, please see (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77d641770e03b5c734c2e9100ebdda3a)

Comment: hello， But when I want to pass it to `get_user_guild_nick`, it doesn’t work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting **as text** — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: thx,@Shepmaster I tried it myself and it has been solved

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove static life time in fields params.

```
pub async fn get_user_guild_nick(
    &self,
    user_id: String,
    fields: Vec<&str>, //<---HERE
) -> Result<HashMap<&'static str, Option<String>>> {

    let mut _con = self.connect.clone();
    let key = KEYMAP["user_nick"].replace("%s1", &user_id);

    let result: Vec<Option<String>> = cmd("hmget")
        .arg(key)
        .arg(&fields)
        .query_async(&mut _con)
        .await
        .unwrap_or(vec![None]);
    let mut map: HashMap<&'static str, Option<String>> = HashMap::new();
    let iter = fields.iter().enumerate();
    for (k, v) in iter {
        map.insert(v, result[k].clone());
    }
    Ok(map)
}
```